# Counting the number of occurrence of each character in a Dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a column in a pyspark dataframe where each entry is a string. I want to create another column using the count of continuous occurrence of characters in Pyspark

```
Sample Input 1: aaabbcca
Sample Output 1: a3b2c2a1

Sample Input 2: aabbbccaa
Sample Output 2: a2b3c2a2
```

I am a newbie in Data Engineering, so I wrote a simple python program to do this which is working fine -

```
name = input("enter the characters")
count = 1
strng = ""
for i in range(0,len(name)-1):
    if name[i] == name[i+1]:
        count = count+1
    else:
        strng = strng+name[i]
        strng = strng+str(count)
        count = 1
    if i==len(name)-2:
        if name[i]!=name[i+1]:
            strng = strng+name[i+1]+"1"
        else:
            strng = strng+name[i]+str(count)
print(strng)
```

However, when i try to apply this function to a column in a pyspark dataframe, i am getting an error.

my Dataframe is -

```
+-----------+
|      words|
+-----------+
|   aaabbcca|
|  aabbbccaa|
|       abcd|
|    dddeert|
|aaabbbacccd|
+-----------+
```

my expected output is -

```
+-----------+-----------+
|      words|coded_words|
+-----------+-----------+
|   aaabbcca|   a3b2c2a1|
|  aabbbccaa|   a2b3c2a2|
|       abcd|   a1b1c1d1|
|    dddeert|   d3e2r1t1|
|aaabbbacccd| a3b3a1c3d1|
+-----------+-----------+
```

here is my code-

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import  pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_conf = SparkConf()
    my_conf.set("spark.app.name","my 1st app")
    my_conf.set("spark.master","local[*]")

    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=my_conf).getOrCreate()

    def code_func(name):
        count = 1
        strng = ""
        ln = length(name)
        for i in name:
            if name[i] == name[i + 1]:
                count = count + 1
            else:
                strng = strng + name[i]
                strng = strng + str(count)
                count = 1
            if i == len(name) - 2:
                if name[i] != name[i + 1]:
                    strng = strng + name[i + 1] + "1"
                else:
                    strng = strng + name[i] + str(count)
        return strng

    df = spark.read.format("csv").option("path",     "C:/Users/hp/OneDrive/Desktop/ddd.txt").load().toDF("words")
    df2 = df.withColumn("coded_words", code_func(f.col("words")))
    df2.show()
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pysparkLearning\practice\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    df2 = df.withColumn("coded_words", code_func(f.col("words")))
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pysparkLearning\practice\test.py", line 18, in code_func
    for i in name:
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pysparkLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\column.py", line 344, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

how to work on a column values as string and how to solve this particular problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restructure your function so that it takes the string from the row of the column as an input. Then you can apply this function row-wise by making it a `udf`.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def count_consecutive_characters(name):
    count = 1
    strng = ""
    for i in range(0,len(name)-1):
        if name[i] == name[i+1]:
            count = count+1
        else:
            strng = strng+name[i]
            strng = strng+str(count)
            count = 1
        if i==len(name)-2:
            if name[i]!=name[i+1]:
                strng = strng+name[i+1]+"1"
            else:
                strng = strng+name[i]+str(count)
    return strng

df = spark.createDataFrame(["aaabbcca","aabbbccaa","abcd","dddeert","aaabbbacccd"], "string").toDF("words")
df2 = df.withColumn("coded_words", count_consecutive_characters(f.col("words")))

+-----------+-----------+
|      words|coded_words|
+-----------+-----------+
|   aaabbcca|   a3b2c2a1|
|  aabbbccaa|   a2b3c2a2|
|       abcd|   a1b1c1d1|
|    dddeert|   d3e2r1t1|
|aaabbbacccd| a3b3a1c3d1|
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the two salient parts of the traceback:

`line 18, in code_func for i in name`

and

`TypeError: Column is not iterable`

When you're running the PySpark version, a data frame column is being passed to your function, but that column is not iterable (you can't loop over it like you can a string).

Instead you want to call your function once for each *item* in the column, not once with the column itself.